# What is the connection between Lamarck's Mediterranean mussel and the province of Gallia?

Tags: terminology, biology

The scientific name of the Mediterranean Mytilus is [*Mytilus galloprovincialis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediterranean_mussel), with [Lamarck being reported as the creator](http://www.marinespecies.org/aphia.php?p=taxdetails&id=140481). I wonder where this name comes from, in particular what is the (supposed) connection to the Gallia province?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This mussel, indigenous to the Mediterranean but since spread across the globe by human activity, was first described in:

M. Chevalier de Lamarck, *Histoire naturelle des animaux sans vertèbres*, Tome sixième, 1<sup>re</sup> partie, (Paris: February - June 1819), p. 126 ([online](http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/47441#page/138/mode/1up))

There the French name is given as "Moule de Provence". [Provence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provence) is a region in the south of France, bordering the Mediterranean. In Roman times it was part of a province called first Gallia Transalpina, then [Gallia Narbonensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallia_Narbonensis), but commonly known simply as "Provincia" (= province), from which we get the French name.

*galliaprovincialis* is simply the Latin version of "de Provence", referring to the place where the mussel was originally found according to Lamarck's description: near [Martigues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martigues) in Provence, a small town in the vicinity of Marseille.